# Mac Numbers : Calculate Date (by adding number of weeks to a date)

Tags: macos, apple-numbers

How do I add a number of weeks to a date in Mac Numbers ?

Eg - How do I calculate the value for cell C1 in the below

```
Cell A1 = Project Start Date      (Date)
Cell B1 = Project Length in Weeks (Number)
Cell C1 = Project End Date        (Date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in cell C1 enter:

=A+B*7

And you will get the wanted result

Comment: Many thanks, thats brilliant. I wouldn't have thought that would work but it does. Thank you.

Comment: It would be kind if you mark my post as answer.